# Weak formulation General concept

Tags: soft-question, sobolev-spaces, duality-theorems, linear-pde

I am searching for a reference where weak formulation accure algebraicly, I found in Wikipedia a genral concept for weak formulation which goes from duality, you can see it([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_formulation#General_concept)) .

But I want another  reference in literature , all what I get is about PDE  weak formulation using integrals. Can someone help? I want a reference to this genral concept.

Comment: Maybe you do not want weak solution, but distributional solutions? There, the dual products are mainly used (instead of integrals, since solutions are not regular enough).